# Does XenDesktop expose a Push Notification service

Tags: c#, powershell, xendesktop

I have been reading the XenDesktop API looking to gather session data and found Get-BrokerSession provides the information i'm looking for.

What i have been unable to find is a means for XenDesktop to push a message to my service when the session state changes (or any other data for that matter).

Do you know if its just not a feature available from XenDesktop or if i have missed something in the documentation?

Note: At present this is research and don't have a service in place.  I'm a C# developer but don't have any problems using a more suitable platform if i can get the data i want in a timely fashion.